# Java Springboot consume rest api map to a model

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm trying to map the response of an API to my object:

```
class Person {
  private Long id;
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;

  public Person(Long id, String firstname, String lastname)
...
```

and my api call looks like:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Person person = restTemplate.getForObject("http://xxx/getPerson", Person.class);
```

Which returns a json that looks like:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "firstname": "first",
 "lastname": "last"
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class xxx.Person]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `xxx.Person` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 5]
```

Any idea why?
I have a constructor in my class so I'm not too sure why this is throwing an error. Thanks!

Comment: create default constructor in your pojo class

Comment: since you have args constructor, it is your responsibility to create no arg constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception clearly points out:

> (no Creators, like default construct, exist)

You have no **default constructor** for your class `Person`.

> Any idea why?

Because you **explicitly** defined a constructor and just due to this behavior, the **default** constructor will not be generated automatically.

So you should deal with it, and there are two things you need to care about:

1. providing a `default constructor` either you defining it explicitly or using an *lombok* annotation `@NoArgsConstructor`;
2. another headsup might be properties mismatching issue, if the json doesn't have all the properties your `class` defines, you should also ignore them explicitly by `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` to the class or add `@JsonIgnore` for the extra fields separately.

Comment: Great it was so stupid! I just needed to have an empty constructor. Thx guys!

Comment: Just curious ... if he has an empty constructor and no setters, how can jackson actually set these field values?  Wouldn't they all be private?

Comment: Seems Jackson using reflection

Comment: @Nibras I think it's a design balance: since you're explicitly creating your own. JVM helps when you left it empty - a sugar perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Default Constructor in your `Person` class, you can create it manually or you can use lombok `@NoargConstructor` on top of class to create it

Since you declared argument constructor it's your responsibility to create no arg constructor

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a default Constructor first. Also, you can use     `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation to ignore any other attributes than those defined in the model.

Take a look at this example - https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/